# $−i$ and $i$ are not quantitatively equivalent

Tags: complex-numbers

In this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit), the author says that "although −i and i are not quantitatively equivalent". What does he mean?

> However, no ambiguity results as long as one or other of the solutions is chosen and labelled as "i", with the other one then being labelled as −i. This is because, although −i and i are not quantitatively equivalent (they are negatives of each other), there is no algebraic difference between i and −i.

Comment: He means that they are two distinct complex numbers.

Comment: The author says in this article: "Being a quadratic polynomial with no multiple root, the defining equation $x^2 = −1$ has two distinct solutions, which are equally valid, namely $i$ and $-i$". So $i$ and $-i$ are distinct.